# If $J$ is an interval then $f(J)$ is an interval (if $f$ is continuous)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Stumbled upon a proof of one lemma. The statement of the lemma is quite obvious, but something in the proof does not seem to make sense very easily for me. Hence my asking.

**Statement**: Let $f$ be continuous on an interval $J$. Let $f(J)$ denote the collection of all values $f(x)$, for $x$ in $J$. Then $f(J)$ is also an interval.

**Proof (part thereof)**: Suppose that $f(J)$ were not an interval. Then there would exist two numbers $y$ and $z$ in $f(J)$, with $y<z$, and a number $p$ in $(y, z)$ such that $p$ is not in the range of $f$. [...]

*What I don't understand:* Why does there have to be a $p$ outside of the range of $f$, and, say, not in the set of $f(J)$?

Comment: Any interval is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the proof assumes $J$ is the domain of $f$ and therefore $f(J)$ is exactly the range of $f$.

Now define $T = \sup \{f(x) \colon x \in J\}$ and B = $\inf \{f(x) \colon x \in J\}$.

Then we have $B \le f(x) \le T$ for each $x \in J$.

Supposing each element of the interval $(B,T)$ looks like $f(x)$ for some $x \in J$, then $f(J)$ can only be one of $[B,T], (B,T], [B,T)$ or $(B,T)$.

In any of the four cases $f(J)$ is an interval.

So supposing $f(J)$ is not an interval gives some $p \in (B,T)$ outside the range of $f$. Then we can use properties of the $\sup$ and $\inf$ to choose $y,x \in \mathbb R$ such that $B < f(y) < p < f(z) < T$.

Comment: It's not said in the Lemma that $f(J)$ is assumed to be the domain of $f$. Otherwise, it would've been clear.

Comment: In that case you should define a new function by restricting the domain of $f$ to the interval $J$, and apply the proof I gave to the new function. It should also be clear that the image of $J$ under the new function coincides with the image under $f$.

Comment: Then I gather that the author of the book just wasn't rigorous enough, or wasn't clear enough, and missed this important detail, which has led to the confusion.